# Tomcat not Executing load-on-startup in Fedora

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, tomcat8

I have a servlet that is defined in web.xml as (load-on-startup)1(/load-on-startup), because I want to initialise some stuff while starting tomcat to conserve request time. In MyEclipse 2014 pro, when I start tomcat 8.0.3, it actually initialises that servlet. In fedora 17 x64 (from DigitalOcean.com) when I start tomcat using: "service tomcat start" it just starts the basic tomcat and it does not actually initialise that servlet. Is there a special command MyEclipse executes to handle that? What command do I have to enter in fedora so that it actuallyinitialises my web.xml while it starts tomcat?

Thank you

Comment: How do you manually deploy application? Are you making war ? If yes, than it is best habit to make war from eclipse using File >> export >> war(Export a Web Module into an external WAR file)

Answer (score 0):

I have deployed the app locally in my AMD and then I copied/pasted the content of tomcat/webapps/ROOT/* to the server in DigitalOcean using WinSCP